# Prevent front-end from reformatting long fractions while editing

Tags: front-end, boxes, editing, formatting

I am editing an expression containing wide fractions (typeset with fraction boxes):

[image: Nicely typeset equation]

But if, while editing the equation, the fraction exceeds some threshold (seems to be approximately the window width), the front-end will helpfully replace my nicely-typeset fraction box

$$\frac{\text{numerator numerator numerator}}{\text{denominator denominator denominator}}$$

with `(numerator numerator numerator)/(denominator denominator denominator)` (on one line, with parentheses added). This also happens if you write the equation correctly, and then resize the window to be narrower than the fraction (even if the cursor isn't in that cell!)

[image: RUINED]

The automatic reformatting persists after resizing the window back:

[image: RUINED FOREVER]

The result is an unreadable jumble.

This is a serious problem for anyone using a tiling window manager.

The same issue occurs with wide expressions inside of square-root signs.

Is it possible to disable this behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try setting the option `FractionBoxOptions`, suboption [`MultilineFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MultilineFunction.html) to `None` for the style, or globally.

Comment: Relevant: http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MultilineFunction.html

Comment: Nice contribution @Mechanicalsnail

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `ctrl+shift+T` to force the cell displayed as `TraditionalForm,` or `ctrl+shift+I` to `InputForm`, or `ctrl+shift+N` to StandardForm

Comment: What does this have to do with the question?